# Electron app close dialog with message box confirmation

Tags: javascript, electron

I use Electron v13.0.1 from this [repo](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron)

Need close confirmation, use this implementation:

```
win.on('close', function (e) {
    require('electron').dialog.showMessageBox(this, {
        type: 'question',
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
        title: 'Confirm',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
    }).then(function (data) {
        if (data.response === 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

But when I click on the close button dialog appeared on second and the application close without any confirmation or rejection. In other words, the dialog does not create conjunction for close.

What is the problem with my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling an asynchronous method and the event function continues execution and eventually returns, before any user input is given.

One way to solve this is to use the `showMessageBoxSync` function for synchronous operation. This will wait until user selects an option before continuing execution. Like below:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron');

win.on('close', function (e) {
    let response = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(this, {
        type: 'question',
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
        title: 'Confirm',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
    });

    if(response == 1) e.preventDefault();
});
```